# Does anybody know Yammer-like app, developed using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, collaboration, yammer

all

I found Yammer a very useful, and great app, but i want to extend it somehow. 
And want to have it installed as on-premise solution.

Maybe someone know alternative for it, but developed using C#? 
Thx

Comment: You mean open source alternative?

Comment: Hi, @svick! Yes, i mean open-source alternative. Like http://leiha.codeplex.com/ but with more functionality from the box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exist many open-source self-hosted alternatives to Yammer, such as StatusNet and Laconi.ca, but unfortunately, most of them are in PHP/MySQL.

Currently, [Leiha](http://leiha.codeplex.com/) is your best bet.